# How would I say "of the silk road" as in a male dog or horse or cat from the silk road?

Tags: узус

How would I say "of the silk road"  as in a male dog or horse or cat from the Silk Road?

By "the Silk Road" I mean the ancient general route or area stretching from Russia, Central Asia and China.

E.g. "Maxim of the Silk Road" or from the Silk Road/Silk Route.

Maxim is the name of an animal e.g. a cat, or dog or horse.

The second part would be a family name - meaning "of the Silk Route".

And how would I write it in English using the Latin alphabet?

Would *Maxim Шелкового пути*, i.e. "Maxim Shelkovogo" or "Maxim Shelkovog Put" make sense? Or would "Maxim Shelkovoy" or "Maxim Shelkovoy Dorogi" make more sense?

Comment: Максим Шёлко(во)путный? (never mind, this is a humoristic suggestion)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Unfortunately, the way your question is put now it's very hard to tell what exactly are you trying to ask. We'd be grateful if you provided the original English phrase you're trying to translate along with its brief explanation. I can't understand what is "male dog/horsecat from the silk road" supposed to mean. Thanks!

Comment: is [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkYS3IXhEdI) what you mean by 'horsecat'?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Let me rephrase.

Comment: Thankyou for your very kind replies. Sorry for the lack of clarity. Let me rephrase. How would I say a name created to mean "Maxim of the Silk Road" or "Maxim from the Silk Road"?  I understand "Maxim of Leningrad" could written "Maxim Leningradskaya"? In a similar way, the name "Jack London" would originally have signified "Jack from London". Am I correct in the usage of names and their application?

Comment: @JohnWalker: is Maxim supposed to be an animal name? Is "Silk Road" supposed to mean "The Silk Road" as in the ancient Chinese trade route, or just a street named "Silk Road"? If yes, is it a street in an English-speaking town or not? Could you please use the phrase you are trying to translate in context? Please edit your post to address all those issues, not just leave replies in the comments, this would help the others see your intent more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've edited the original question to be more clear.

Answer (score 5):

The literal answer to your question would be *Максим с Шёлкового Пути* ("Maxim s Shelkovogo Puti" or "Maksim s Sholkavava Puti", depending on whether you want transliteration or transcription).

That said, I am assuming you are trying to use this name in a piece of fiction, and if that's the case, there are a couple of issues with this phrase.

First of all, "The Silk Road" is a historiographical term: it had been coined by modern historians to describe a certain entity which lacked a contemporary name. People who used the Silk Road did not call it "The Silk Road", and it's very unlikely they were at all aware that such a thing existed. This means that a name like this could not be used to call an animal in a realistic setting. Of course your mileage can vary if your setting involves time-travel or sci-fi or something like that when people from the future would want to name an animal from the past.

Second, the "Silk Road" part of this phrase is not a Russian last name. Most Russian last names are formed according to several paradigms (*-ов/-ев, -ин/-ын, -ий/-ый, -ой, -ович/евич* etc.) and in most cases to form a Russian last name from a dictionary word you'd need to shoehorn it into one of those paradigms. Those paradigms are only remotely related to the way the modern language works.

Russian for "Silk Road" is *Шёлковый путь* or *Великий Шёлковый путь*, which is quite a cumbersome phrase, and it's a challenge to make a nice-sounding Russian surname out of it which would still point to its original.

You could try and use something like *Шелкопутный* or *Шелкопутский* or something like this, but those would not immediately strike the reader with a meaning of "from the Silk Road", they would need to be reminded of that.

If you provided us with more context on how you are going to use this name in your work, we'd probably be able to give you a better advice.